# Accessing Cloud Run secret in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, docker-volume

I'm rather new to Spring Boot, and I'm having a tough time on a seemingly simple problem. I have setup a Google Cloud Run instance with a secret mounted in a volume - it's a JSON file with a firebase token. As shown in the screenshot below, the file's mount path is `/secrets`

[image]

Based on this, I was expecting to simply need to do the following in my Spring Boot app to load the file and initialize Firebase:

```
File file = new File("secrets/firebase-token"); 
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
var credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(fileInputStream);
var options = FirestoreOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build();
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a special way to access the volume's path in Cloud Run?

Thanks in advance!!

P.S: this works well in localhost with a firebase-token path on my machine.

Comment: What's your error? Do you mount several secret in the same time on the same mount path?

Comment: hi @guillaumeblaquiere! Interestingly, I don't have an error when building the container (I'm using Google Cloud Build and the automated deployment features of Cloud Run). My container seems to build perfectly fine. However, when pinging my test endpoint (here: https://sentinel-backend-service-dev-fs35rxplsq-uc.a.run.app/getPing). I get Google's default error as if the deployment failed - my guess is that my app crashes when attempting to initialize Firebase. I have a hunch it is the way I try to recover the secrets from the mounted volume that's wrong. Also, I have only this one secret.

Comment: Building a container is not the problem. It's like a ZIP but in a different format. So, you can easily understand that it's not at the build time that you can have an issue. Thus, it's at runtime. Do you have more detail in Cloud Logging?